# ESRI JAVASCRIPT API - Can you return a list of fields from a published Querylayer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, query-layer

I have a query layer that is published onto arcGIS server. I am having difficulty returning the fields in a javascript application. I need to be able to iterate over this array. Code is bellow.. ServiceURL and HEatMapOptions are defined elsewhere before any of this is called. The function returns undefined..

```
var heatmapOptions = {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
    outFields: ["*"]
}; //end of options
var heatmapFeatureLayer = new FeatureLayer(serviceURL, heatmapOptions);
    var heatmapRenderer = new HeatmapRenderer();
    heatmapRenderer.blurRadius = 6;
    heatmapFeatureLayer.setRenderer(heatmapRenderer);
    map.addLayer(heatmapFeatureLayer);

function getFields(h) {
    var lyr = h;
    var f = lyr.fields;
    console.log(f);

};

on(heatmapFeatureLayer, "load", getFields(heatmapFeatureLayer));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because getFields is being called immediately. To avoid this, wrap it in a function.

```
on(heatmapFeatureLayer, "load", function(){
 getFields(heatmapFeatureLayer)
});
```

Comment: Bingo! Callbacks throw me off every time.